# Unknown error messages in bam model (mgcv) using family=betar

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm running the following `bam` model in mgcv:

```
model <- bam(x~s(y, by=aa, k=-1) + aa + s(bb, bs='re') + s(lat,long), family=betar, data=dataframe)
```

where y is continuous, and aa and bb are categorical predictors. To account for spatial autocorrelation, lat and long are included as a smoothed interaction term. The data frame is **very** large (>2 million rows, hence the `bam` approach). The model seems to run with the correct df after many hours, and the plots look correct, but the model gives the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In wt * LS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In muth * (log(y) - log1p(-y)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In prior.weights * y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In 2 * wt * (-lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) -  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I've tried to Google these, but I can't find any context to help understand. I've tried generating dummy data, but given the size of the data and complexity of the model, I'm struggling to provide a reproducible example. How concerned should I be by these warning messages, and can anyone help interpret them?

Edit: I've updated with dummy code below to show the structure of the `bam` model, but I can't get it to reproduce the same error as above:

```
library(mgcv)

beta <- 0.0002
n <- 1000

set.seed(1)
lat <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 100)
set.seed(2)
long <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 100)

temp1a <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="a", category="a")
temp1b <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="b", category="a")
temp1c <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="c", category="a")
temp1d <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="d", category="a")
temp1e <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="e", category="a")

temp2a <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="a", category="b")
temp2b <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="b", category="b")
temp2c <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="c", category="b")
temp2d <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="d", category="b")
temp2e <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="e", category="b")

temp3a <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="a", category="c")
temp3b <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="b", category="c")
temp3c <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="c", category="c")
temp3d <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="d", category="c")
temp3e <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="e", category="c")

temp4a <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="a", category="d")
temp4b <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="b", category="d")
temp4c <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="c", category="d")
temp4d <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="d", category="d")
temp4e <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), long=long, lat=lat, time = seq(n), model="e", category="d")

df <- rbind(temp1a,temp1b,temp1c,temp1d,temp1e,temp2a,temp2b,temp2c,temp2d,temp2e,temp3a,temp3b,temp3c,temp3d,temp3e,temp4a,temp4b,temp4c,temp4d,temp4e)
df$model <- as.factor(df$model)
df$category <- as.factor(df$category)
df$time <- as.numeric(df$time)
df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)
str(df)

df$y [df$y == 1] <- 0.999999
df$y [df$y == 0] <- 0.000001

m1 <- bam(y~s(time, by=category, k=-1) + category + s(model, bs='re') + s(long,lat), family=betar, data=df)
```

(apologies for the poor code above in advance)

Edit #2: included str(df) for the actual data below:

```
'data.frame':   3453552 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ long    : num  11.7 11.6 11.5 11.4 11.3 11.2 11.1 11 10.9 10.8 ...
 $ lat     : num  75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 ...
 $ bb   : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ aa: Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ y      : num  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ x    : num  0.0342 0.0128 0.0118 0.0101 0.0079 ...
```

Comment: I think vectors of different length being passed to mathematical operators should be a strong concern.  I'm not familiar with `bam` models or the `betar` family but, assuming that you followed the documentation (is `bam` documented to work with this family?), this might be a bug.

Comment: Are `aa` and `bb` *factors*? They have to be for random effects but there are not checks to insure this and hence you can get a all sorts of weird errors as a result. As R no longer coerces characters to factors we're seeing more people hitting this issue.

Comment: @Roland - bam [does work with the betar family](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/Beta.html) although I haven't experimented with the arguments. The data is bound by 0 and 1 but doesn't contain 0 and 1 values. The dataframe doesn't contain any missing values, so I'm a bit confused as to where the vectors of different length issue is coming into play?

Comment: @GavinSimpson I've checked this explicitly before running the model using 'str(df)' and aa and bb are definitely factors.

Comment: Does it work if you fit a simpler model? (It could be that all those terms aren't needed and the model is getting into weird territory.) Failing that, it might be work contacting Simon Wood with a reproducible example (or your actual example data) as this suggests at the very least that an unforeseen situation is causing issues with some of the code logic.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I've tried a simpler model without the s(long,lat) and it still forces the same error. I've included code above to simulate the model structure, but I can't make it force a reproducible error, which makes me think there's something about the underlying structure of the dataset I'm using...

Comment: I suspect this is true, and hence why sending Simon the exact data and script you are using (or links to the data if it is large) is going to be essential. Can you post the output from `str(datafframe)` here so we can at least see the structure.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I've updated the str(df) in the main text above. If that doesn't flag any errors I'll send Simon Wood an email today

Comment: Nothing there jumps out at me as being obviously wrong, so I think an email to Simon is in order