# GAM error using bam() with family = betar

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm having trouble solving an error I am getting when running `bam()` from `mgcv`.

I note that a similar error was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091468/unknown-error-messages-in-bam-model-mgcv-using-family-betar) 14 months ago and there seemed to be no agreed on solution - with the suggestion being to email Simon Wood.

My data are [here](https://environmentnswgov-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/pat_taggart_dpie_nsw_gov_au/EQ_frCO6O6NJhtmjXnMkWCsB9dlewUnLMW560Ch_F8B5Qw?e=mmVg0v). The data set is too big to paste the output of `dput()`.

If I run the below model using the entire data set I get the below errors

```
library(mgcv)

m3 <- bam(pt10 ~ 
            org.type +
            region +
            s(year) + 
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region), 
          data = error, 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit", eps = 0.1),
          select = T)

Warning messages:
1: In estimate.theta(theta, family, G$y, linkinv(eta), scale = scale1,  :
  step failure in theta estimation
2: In wt * LS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In muth * (log(y) - log1p(-y)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In prior. weights * y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
8: In 2 * wt * (-lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) -  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

However, if I run the same model using the entire dataset, **but** I exclude the last row, the model appears to run ok

```
m3 <- bam(pt10 ~ 
            org.type +
            region +
            s(year) + 
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region), 
          data = error[1:20500,], 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit", eps = 0.1),
          select = T)
```

This suggested to me that there was something wrong in the last row of the data set. However, I cannot see any errors in the last row of the data set that I would expect to produce the above warning messages.

If I again run the same model on a small subset of the data, but this time include the last row of data, the model again appears to run ok.

```
m3 <- bam(pt10 ~ 
            org.type +
            region +
            s(year) + 
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region), 
          data = error[20400:20501,], 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit", eps = 0.1),
          select = T)
```

But a larger subset of the data, again including the last row, produces similar warning messages to above.

```
m3 <- bam(pt10 ~ 
            org.type +
            region +
            s(year) + 
            s(year, by = org.type) +
            s(year, by = region), 
          data = error[10000:20501,], 
          method = "fREML", 
          family = betar(link="logit", eps = 0.1),
          select = T)

Warning messages:
1: In wt * LS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In muth * (log(y) - log1p(-y)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In -lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) - muth *  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In prior.weights * y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In 2 * wt * (-lgamma(theta) + lgamma(muth) + lgamma(theta - muth) -  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
8: In bgam.fit(G, mf, chunk.size, gp, scale, gamma, method = method,  :
  algorithm did not converge
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your `eps` (which probably does indicate that you have issues with the data).

The default is:

```r
r$> .Machine$double.eps*100                                                     
[1] 2.220446e-14
```

so you are truncating all your response values to the interval `[eps, 1-eps]` (i.e. anything `y < eps` or `y > 1-eps` is being reset to `eps` and `1 - eps` respectaively.). I suppose that is causing problems with the fitting algorithm  and that it is encountering situations that were not anticipated. If there are a not insignificant number of values that are outside the range `[eps, 1-eps]`, you will be piling all those values up on the limits of the range and I suspect that is leading to situations where subtle changes in the data are leading to numerical problems in the fitting algorithm.

Truncating the data as much as you are doing suggests this is not the right distribution for your data. Absent any other information I'd look elsewhere for a more suitable method.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, appreciated. My outcome is a percentage, which I have scaled to the range 0-1 (```dat$pt10``` was previously on the range 0-100). This was why I chose ```family = betar()```. I have no values of ```NA``` or blank cells in my outcome variable, or in any of my predictor variables. All variables included in my model have a length of 70645. Any advice on alternate distributions or how I might make further progress on solving these errors?

Comment: The obvious question then is why did you change `eps` to be so large?

Comment: Simple answer is naivety. I didn't realise that the default was so small. I have also tried transforming the 0's and 1's in my outcome variable using the method by Smithson & Verkuilen 2006 Psychological Methods V11. The model runs. I no longer get the ```algorithm did not converge``` warning but I still get same warnings about ```longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length```. The model shows the effects that I was expecting to see but has a negative deviance explained - perhaps an error that is already known and due to be fixed in next version of mgcv, feel I read this

Comment: A zero-one inflated beta would cope with the true 0s and 1s; fitting in brms would allow the same smooths as your mgcv-based GAM. Warnings of that sort are almost always a bug (even if they don't affect anything) as some operation is expecting vectors of equal length but for some reason one or both have changed lengths (differently). If you can share your data with Simon Wood or come up with an example that raises the same problems with the latest version of mgcv then I would send them and the relevant R code to him so he can take a look. -ve deviance expl is also a bad sign.